# Deploying firebase function with puppeteer says chrome can't be found even thoough I have enabled --no-sandbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I'm trying to deploy a firebase function to my firebase project that use puppeteer, I have it working on my local machine, but when it tries running on firebase I get this error:

```
"Exception from a finished function: Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (1045629)."
```

I've saw other people online saying to use the --no-sand box flag, which I have already tried but it's still throwing this error

This is my code for initializing puppeteer:

```
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
```

The node version is set to 16 in my package.json and puppeteer is version 19.0.0

I would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: In version 19.0.0, the browser location folder has changed to `~/.cache/puppeteer` instead of node_modules. Is it possible for you to verify if the browser is downloaded there? Also, if you run your function with the env variable `DEBUG=puppeteer:*`, the log should give more info about what goes wrong.

Comment: As suggested in this [github](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/issues/253) try running this command `node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js`

Comment: I'm getting this exact same issue. Sathi when I run that command I just get the message "Chromium is already in C:\Users\me\.cache\puppeteer\chrome\win64-1045629; skipping download."

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: I ended up using heroku, cause there was only one extra step to get it working where it was just searching / linking for the puppeteer package, but my server ran out of memory. 

Puppeteer seems to be really convoluted for some certain things. I think using selenium with python is honestly the best way to go for automation type stuff like this.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and was able to resolve it by installing puppeteer at the earlier 18.2.1 version (`npm i puppeteer@18.2.1`). I think the error is a result of this -> https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration/

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar problem on M1 Mac. Puppeteer could not find Chrome because Firebase Functions run on linux, and puppeteer downloaded only Mac version.

I moved puppeteer's cache into project folder to make sure it is included into the build package, and set up a script to automatically download Chrome for linux on every deploy.

`.puppeteerrc.cjs`. Moved `cacheDirectory` to the project folder.

```js
const { join } = require('path');

/**
* @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
*/
module.exports = {
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};
```

`util/puppeteer-downloader.js`. This script downloads Chrome specific for the installed puppeteer version and places it into `cacheDirectory` specified above.

```js
const { PUPPETEER_REVISIONS } = require('puppeteer-core');
const { install } = require('@puppeteer/browsers');
const config = require('../.puppeteerrc.cjs');
    
const buildId = PUPPETEER_REVISIONS.chrome;
const cacheDir = config.cacheDirectory;

async function downloadChrome(platform) {
  console.log('Installing Chrome version', buildId, 'for platform', platform, 'to', cacheDir);
  try {
    await install({ platform, browser: 'chrome', buildId, cacheDir });
    console.log('Chrome installed successfully');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Chrome installation failed', err);
    throw err;
  }
}

(async () => {
  await downloadChrome('linux');
})().catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

`firebase.json`. Clears `.cache` folder to make sure only linux version is installed. Otherwise other versions also will be included into deploy package, bloating it and wasting Firebase storage and bandwidth quotas.

```json
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": ".",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
      "tsc",
      "rm -rf .cache",
      "node ./util/puppeteer-downloader.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This can be improved further to avoid re-downloading Chrome every time, but this is good enough for me for now.

Packages:

```
- firebase-functions: 4.4.1
- puppeteer: 21.1.1
```